# RunProcess PowerShell command to obtain Active Directory groups

Tags: external-calls

Is it possible to run this Windows cmd command in `RunProcess`?

```
powershell "([ADSISEARCHER]\"samaccountname=$($env:USERNAME)\").Findone().Properties.memberof -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'"
```

The shorter version below does not return the same output as the Windows command line, although it does not error.  The output is useless though.

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell,
 "StandardOutput",
 "powershell ([ADSISEARCHER]\"samaccountname=$($env:USERNAME)\").Findone().Properties.memberof"]
```

Actually the output is the same as for this different command.

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell,
 "StandardOutput",
 "whoami /groups"]
```

However, this can be successfully run in slightly different syntax:

```
RunProcess[{"whoami", "/groups"}, "StandardOutput"]
```

(Successful in the sense that it runs, but it fails to report all the groups that the powershell method correctly does.)

***For what it's worth***

The following works in Windows but hangs in Citrix.

```
 RunProcess[{"powershell", "Get-Help"}, "StandardOutput"]
```

The following gives the useless output in Windows *and* Citrix (surprisingly).

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", "powershell Get-Help"]
```

The following gives useful output in Windows but just returns an empty list in Citrix.

```
ReadList["!powershell Get-Help", String]
```

***Last resort***

Use the much slower gpresult -- slower because it does lots of other things.

```
RunProcess[{"gpresult", "/r", "/scope:user"}, "StandardOutput"]
```

Comment: Why would it not be? If you're running into troubles my guess is that the environment path variable isn't quite what it is in your terminal.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Can you elaborate?  My system admin and I cannot use your info.

Comment: Without knowing what your error is I can't be certain, but my guess is that `ProcessEnvironment` can't find the executable because whatever path variable in `Environment` Windows uses is different from its corresponding value on the command line.